# Can I use htaccess to Remove a phantom ? from the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Google is somehow indexing some phantom URL's for my website. I'm still trying to find the problem.

For example, everything in bold below is NOT supposed to be there.

http://www.mydomain.com/directory/sights**?/kauai/sights/sights/kalalau_lookout**

It should look like this:
http://www.mydomain.com/directory/sights

How can I strip out the ? mark in addition to everything after it and make it 301 redirect to the proper page?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Are your URLs really flat or are you using .htaccess rewrite already?

Comment: I'm already using htaccess to remove index.php from the URLs

Answer (score 0):

From [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

> **Modifying the Query String**
>   By default, the query string is passed through unchanged.
>   ...
>   *When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark.*
>   ...

You can remove all query strings with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule .* http://www.mydomain.com$0?
```